# calculate percentage of strings instead of statistics

Tags: python, statistics, percentage, letter

I would like to calculate the percentage of each letter in my file instead of the number. How can I modify the following code?

```
stat_file = open(filename, 'w')
one_letter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for letter in one_letter:
    stat_file.writelines('%s : %d \n' % (letter, statistics[letter]))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the total letter counts can have two meanings:

**1. Only the words in `one_letter` (only 'A-Z' in your question)**

```
one_letter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
stat = {'A': 5, 
          'B':3, 
          'C':9, 
          'U': 5, 
          'D': 9, 
          'a': 99}

total_count = sum(stat.get(letter, 0) for letter in one_letter) # should be 31
```

**2. All the words in your file (including 'a-z', '0-9', ...)**

```
total_count = sum(stat.values()) # should be 130
```

After that, you can calculate your percentage by

```
for letter in one_letter:
    stat_file.writelines("%s: %f%%\n" %(letter, \
        stat.get(letter, 0)/float(total_count)*100))
```

Be reminded that `stat.get(letter, 0)` just for the case if not all letters in `stat`.

You can replaced with `stat[letter]` if you sure `A-Z` are in `stat`.

Comment: Btw, how can I get additional statistics that combines more than one letter. For example, percentage of A+B?

Comment: You mean `(stat['A']+stat['B'])/float(total_count)*100)` ?

Comment: I mean, there will be percentage for each residues and at last, there will also be percentage for few combinations. Everything in same file.

Comment: sorry for confusing comments but I just figured out myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the sum of all letters like this:

```
letter_count=0
for letter in one_letter:
    letter_count= letter_count + statistics[letter]
```

then to get the percentage you need to change your code like this:

```
stat_file.writelines('%s : %d %% \n' % (letter, (statistics[letter]/letter_count)*100) if statistics[letter]>0 else 0)
```

NOTE: I haven't tested the code (no python on this pc installed), but it should work.
EDIT: check if the letter has 0 times occurred.

Comment: the resulting file has A:100% and rest are 0%. In addition, I would also like to get the percentage of A+B or C+Z, for example.